# How do I set the height of an element-ui tree node?

Tags: html, element-ui

I'm using element-ui with vue.js and want to set the height of each node to 50.

I tried:

```
    <el-tree
        :data="container.children">
        <span height="50" slot-scope="{ node, data }"  class="custom-tree-node">
        node.label
        </span>
    </el-tree>
```

Unfortunately, the height attribute gets ignored. How do I set the node height correctly?

Comment: Have you tried CSS? The height attribute can only be used on `<canvas>`, `<embed>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<object>`, and `<video>`.

Comment: @JamesCoyle What css would I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS:

```
.custom-tree-node {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<span style="height: 50px" slot-scope="{ node, data }"  class="custom-tree-node">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i just found one: use Deep selector

```
.custom-tree >>> .el-tree-node__content{
   height: 3em;
}
```

for example, give a class named 'custom-tree' to the node el-tree:

```
<el-tree class="custom-tree"
    :data="container.children">
    <span height="50" slot-scope="{ node, data }"  class="custom-tree-node">
    node.label
    </span>
</el-tree>
```